# no dns query is sent for "speedport.ip" by ping/curl but it is resolved via dig/host

Tags: linux, networking, dns

My network looks like this:

```
   ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
   │Notebook    │      │  FW/DNS    │    │ISP ROUTER  │
   │ arch linux ├─────►│mapping:    ├───►│192.168.2.1 │
   │            │      │speedport.ip│    │speedport.ip│
   │            │      │192.168.2.1 │    │            │
   └────────────┘      └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

The FW(Firewall) does dns for my network (Notebook).
So the "speedport.ip" is not resolved normally.
However, i've done a mapping on the FW:

speedport.ip -> 192.168.2.1

this i can verify on the notebook with:

```
# dig speedport.ip

; <<>> DiG 9.18.15 <<>> speedport.ip
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17333
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;speedport.ip.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
speedport.ip.           3600    IN      A       192.168.2.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.2#53(192.168.3.2) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 27 07:53:46 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

I've also verified with tcpdump that dns packages are sent:

```
# tcpdump udp port 53
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:03:43.974915 IP notebook.mydomain.xyz.46555 > fw.mydomain.xyz.domain: 26+ [1au] A? speedport.ip. (53)
08:03:43.975175 IP fw.mydomain.xyz.domain > notebook.mydomain.xyz.46555: 26* 1/0/1 A 192.168.2.1 (57)
```

The issue is, when i do a:

```
[root@notebook]# curl http://speedport.ip
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: speedport.ip
[root@notebook]# ping speedport.ip
ping: speedport.ip: Name or service not known
```

also no dns queries are sent (does not show up in tcpdump).
So my question is now:

Why is no dns query send?

Btw, i can add this entry to the /etc/hosts file of the notebook.
Then it works.

edit:

```
[root@notebook]# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.

passwd: files systemd
group: files [SUCCESS=merge] systemd
shadow: files systemd
gshadow: files systemd

publickey: files

hosts: mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

```
[root@notebook]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search mydomain.xyz
nameserver 192.168.3.2
```

edit2:

```
[root@notebook]# resolvectl 
Global
           Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.3.2
         DNS Servers: 192.168.3.2
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 8.8.8.8#dns.google
                      2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google
          DNS Domain: mydomain.xyz

Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.3.2
       DNS Servers: 192.168.3.2
```

Comment: Yes, FW is Firewall.

Comment: edited @DanielB

Comment: Since your 2nd 'hosts:' module is 'resolve', what is the output of `resolvectl`? Keep in mind that /etc/resolv.conf is only directly used by the 'dns' module that's all the way back (`dig` does not use nsswitch).

Comment: resolvectl is interesting, indeed the firewall does use cloudflare etc as its dns servers,
but i forbid that clients do dns by themself in my network, those fallback dns servers should not be known to the clients.

Comment: Those fallback servers are independent from your firewall configuration, it’s just a coincidence. // Try `tcpdump -n -i any port 53` in combination with `resolvectl query speedport.ip` and `resolvectl query --cache=false speedport.ip`.

Comment: after i flushed the cache `resolvectl flush-caches` it works... Thank you all.